# python tkinter passing dataframes between widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, parameter-passing

My Python tkinter program has several widgets.
Dataframes created in 1 widget(e.g. PyDataTest1), with a name chosen by the user, should also be available in the other widgets. But it seems that's not the case if the widgets have another class.
I wrote 3 python modules: PyDataTestMain, PyDataTest1 and PyDataTest2.
The code for PyDataTest2 is - to keep the example simple - the same as for PyDataTest1 (I only replaced PyDataTest1 by PyDataTest2).
If I save a dataframe in widget p1, I can retrieve it in widget p3, but not in widget p2 and p4. What do I need to change to have it also available there ?

```
'''
    PyDataTestMain.py
'''

#%% Import libraries
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PyDataTest1 import PyDataTest1
from PyDataTest2 import PyDataTest2

#%% Main class
class PyDataTestMain(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add several PyDataTest widgets
        self.p1 = PyDataTest1(self).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.p2 = PyDataTest2(self).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.p3 = PyDataTest1(self).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.p4 = PyDataTest2(self).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

#%% Allow the class to run stand-alone.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PyDataTestMain().mainloop()
```

and

```
'''
    PyDataTest1.py
'''

#%% Import libraries
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import pandas as pd

#%% Main class
class PyDataTest1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()

    def save(self):
        var = self.pythonVar.get()

        global glb
        glb = globals()
        glb[var] = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'BBB' : [43., 32., 21., 10.]})

        messagebox.showinfo("Info","pandas dataframe saved as " + var)

    def listVars(self):
        variables= [var for var in globals() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
        self.comboboxDataframes['values'] = variables

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Allow to enter a name and save the data in the base workspace
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Variable").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.pythonVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.pythonVar.set('d')
        ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.pythonVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        # Save button
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Save", command=self.save).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        # Combobox showing dataframes stored
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Dataframes").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.comboboxDataframes = ttk.Combobox(self, postcommand=self.listVars)
        self.comboboxDataframes.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)    

#%% Allow the class to run stand-alone.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PyDataTest1().mainloop()
```

I adapted the code and put everything in one file.

```
'''
    PyDataTestMain.py
'''

#%% Import libraries
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import pandas as pd

#%% Main class
class PyDataTestMain(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add several PyDataTest widgets
        self.p1 = PyDataTest1(self)
        self.p1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        self.p2 = PyDataTest2(self)
        self.p2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        self.p3 = PyDataTest1(self)
        self.p3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        self.p4 = PyDataTest2(self)
        self.p4.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

class PyDataTest1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()

    def save(self):
        var = self.pythonVar.get()

        #global glb
        #glb = globals()
        self.glb = {}
        self.glb[var] = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'BBB' : [43., 32., 21., 10.]})

        messagebox.showinfo("Info","pandas dataframe saved as " + var)

    def listVars(self):
        #variables= [var for var in globals() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
        variables= [var for var in self.glb() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
        self.comboboxDataframes['values'] = variables

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Allow to enter a name and save the data in the base workspace
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Variable").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.pythonVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.pythonVar.set('d')
        ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.pythonVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        # Save button
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Save", command=self.save).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        # Combobox showing dataframes stored
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Dataframes").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.comboboxDataframes = ttk.Combobox(self, postcommand=self.listVars)
        self.comboboxDataframes.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)    

class PyDataTest2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()

    def save(self):
        var = self.pythonVar.get()

        #global glb
        #glb = globals()
        glb = {}
        glb[var] = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'BBB' : [43., 32., 21., 10.]})

        messagebox.showinfo("Info","pandas dataframe saved as " + var)

    def listVars(self):
        variables= [var for var in globals() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
        self.comboboxDataframes['values'] = variables

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Allow to enter a name and save the data in the base workspace
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Variable").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.pythonVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.pythonVar.set('d')
        ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.pythonVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        # Save button
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Save", command=self.save).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        # Combobox showing dataframes stored
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Dataframes").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.comboboxDataframes = ttk.Combobox(self, postcommand=self.listVars)
        self.comboboxDataframes.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)    


#%% Allow the class to run stand-alone.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PyDataTestMain().mainloop()
```

Comment: if you do `self.p3 = PyDataTest1(self).grid()` then you get `None` in `self.p3` because `grid()` returns `None`. If you need `self.p3` then you have to do it in two lines `self.p3 = PyDataTest1(self)` and `self.p3.grid()`

Comment: In the widget p3 I already get access to the dataframe I save in widget p1.
In the widgets p2 and p4 I don't.
But I will write it as you recommend.
How do I pass the info from p1 to p2 ?

Comment: instead using `globals()` to create variable you should rather use global dictionary `glb = {}` and then inside class `glb[var] = ` without `globals()`

Comment: myabe you have access because you use `globals()` - but it is not prefered. Python uses dictionary to keep data using string as key.

Comment: if `PyDataTest2` has the same code as `PyDataTest2` then why to use `PyDataTest2` if you can use `PyDataTest1`

Comment: you should add this in question at start.

Comment: maybe put all code in one file and put it in question so we could run it to test it and see problem.

Comment: your problem can be that you have classes in different files/modules - and `globals()` means global variables only in this module, not in full program.

Comment: you could create dictionary in main program or main class - ie. `all_dfs = {}` or `self.all_dfs = {}` - and use it as argument in all classes - ie. `self.p1 = PyDataTest1(self, all_dfs)` - and then all classes will have access to this dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you have code in modules and you use `globals()`

But `globals()` gives global variables inside module, not in full program.

---

In main file use dictionary to keep data - it can be global dictionary or dictionary in main class

```
 self.all_dfs = {}
```

and send this dictionary to other classes as argument

```
self.p1 = PyDataTest1(self, self.all_dfs)

self.p2 = PyDataTest2(self, self.all_dfs)
```

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import pandas as pd
from PyDataTest1 import PyDataTest1
from PyDataTest2 import PyDataTest2

class PyDataTestMain(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

        self.all_dfs = {
            # example dataframe at start
            #'a': pd.DataFrame(),
            #'b': pd.DataFrame(),
        }

        self.createWidgets()

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Add several PyDataTest widgets
        self.p1 = PyDataTest1(self, self.all_dfs)
        self.p1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.p2 = PyDataTest2(self, self.all_dfs)
        self.p2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.p3 = PyDataTest1(self, self.all_dfs)
        self.p3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.p4 = PyDataTest2(self, self.all_dfs)
        self.p4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

#---

PyDataTestMain().mainloop()
```

PyDataTest1.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import pandas as pd

class PyDataTest1(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, dfs=None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.dfs = dfs
        if self.dfs is None:
            raise("Need DataFrames dictionary")

    def save(self):
        var = self.pythonVar.get()

        self.dfs[var] = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'BBB' : [43., 32., 21., 10.]})

        messagebox.showinfo("Info","pandas dataframe saved as " + var)

    def listVars(self):
        self.comboboxDataframes['values'] = list(self.dfs.keys())

    #%% Create widgets
    def createWidgets(self):
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Allow to enter a name and save the data in the base workspace
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Variable").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.pythonVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.pythonVar.set('d')
        ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.pythonVar).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        # Save button
        ttk.Button(self, text = "Save", command=self.save).grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)

        # Combobox showing dataframes stored
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Dataframes").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, padx =5, pady=5)
        self.comboboxDataframes = ttk.Combobox(self, postcommand=self.listVars)
        self.comboboxDataframes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem. 
It works perfectly.
Dziękuje bardzo !